# UNPIVOT with SQL Workbench/J and amazon aws redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, unpivot, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to use unpivot on a table.  I'm using Workbench/J as a client to amazon redshift.  The following select statement does not work:

```
SELECT 
  campaign_id,
  C.B,
  C.A
FROM campaign
UNPIVOT 
(
  A FOR B IN (item1, item2, item3)
) AS C
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "for"
>     Position: 62 [SQL State=42601]

If possible, I'd like to use UNPIVOT rather than UNION and it doesn't recognize UNNEST as a function.

Comment: Are you sure it has an `unpivot` function? Not everything supports unpivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UNPIVOT` syntax is correct however not every database supports the function.

You might want to consider using a `UNION ALL`:

```
select campaign_id, 'item1' as B, item1 as A
from campaign
union all
select campaign_id, 'item2' as B, item2 as A
from campaign
union all
select campaign_id, 'item3' as B, item3 as A
from campaign
```